# Systemd Issue For Starting Application

Tags: systemd

I am using a Toradex VF50 board for my application. It has a VF-50 Colibri ARM processor. I have ported a Linux BSP on this, and I am using systemd to start my Qt application. In my Qt application I am parsing some text files for default initialization values.

When I start my application using systemd (multi-user.target) my application is crashing because the application is not able to read the values from the files.

But when I run the same application from a terminal it is running fine without any issues.

The service file which I am using for my application:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Application
After=dropbear.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/root/startup.sh
#Restart=on-failure
#RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`startup.sh` has the command:

```
/bin/sh -c 'source /etc/environment ; /home/root/TestApp -qws'
```

Comment: you didnt include the service file in your post.

Comment: I have added service file in my comments, Please let me know your views on the same

Comment: When systemd runs your script it will provide only a very limited environment. In particular it will not set `HOME` nor `USER`, nor will it change directory to `/home/root`. Perhaps your `TestApp` relies on one of these. Try explicitly setting them in your `startup.sh`, including a `cd` to the right directory.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I have modified my startup.sh file with APPLICATION_PATH=/home/root/ and followed by the cd $APPLICATION_PATH command and it worked on single go as suggested by you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rahul or @meuh, feel free to add either or both answers as an Answer!

Answer (score 1):

When `systemd` runs your script it will provide only a very limited environment. In particular it will not set `HOME` nor `USER`, nor will it change directory to `/home/root`. Perhaps your TestApp relies on one of these. Try explicitly setting them in your `startup.sh`, including a `cd` to the right directory.  My version of systemd just sets:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and the current directory to `/`. You can also provide environment variables in the `[Service]` section with eg:

```
Environment=HOME=/home/root USER=root
```

but note that shell variables are not expanded so you cannot use this to set the path eg with `PATH=/opt/bin:$PATH`.